# Read from a huge MemoryStream in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, memorystream

I use a BinaryReader (`MemoryStream(MyByteArray)`) to read variable sized records and process them all in memory. This works well as long as my bytestream, which is in the array, is less than about 1.7 GB in size. After that (which is the maximum size of an integer in my 64-bit system) you cannot create a larger bytearray, although I have enough real memory. So my solution has been to read the bytestream and split it into several byte arrays.

Now however, I cannot "read" across the byte array boundaries, and, as my data is in a variable format, I cannot ensure that byte arrays always finish on a whole record.

This must be a common problem for people processing very large datasets and still have the need for speed.

How do I handle this problem?

Comment: You should prevent that a byte array of this size is loaded into memory to begin with. Isn't it possible to implement a streaming solution where you only load parts of the array into memory (a buffer)? Do you need random access to these bytes? Or can you use a forward-only solution where you can read the stream from begin to end while processing it (and without looking back). Where does this byte array come from? A file, a web service, ...?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: Reading up on the basics, I realize that memory-mapped files might be slower than normal I/O for sequential access.

Have you tried something like this:

```
var stream = new FileStream("data", 
    FileMode.Open, 
    FileAccess.Read, 
    FileShare.Read, 
    16 * 1024, 
    FileOptions.SequentialScan)

var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
```

<s>If your data resides in a file and you can use .NET 4.0 consider using [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267535.aspx).</s>

You can then either use a [`MemoryMappedViewStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewstream.aspx) to get a stream or use a [`MemoryMappedViewAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor.aspx) to get a `BinaryReader`-like interface.

Comment: Yes. I tried that - unfortunately MemoryMappedFiles are very slow indeed.

Answer (score 4):

For excessively large streams, you shouldn't try dumping it in `MemoryStream` - use things like `FileStream` instead, and talk directly to disk. The inbuilt buffering is usually sufficient, or you can tweak this with things like `BufferedStream` (but I have rarely needed to - but then, I tend to include my own data-processing buffer).

You might also consider things like compression or densely packed data, and serializers designed to work by *streaming* records rather than creating an entire graph at once (although since you mention `BinaryReader`, you may already be doing this highly manually, so this might not be an issue).

Comment: Yes. It is compressed - wuite efficiently and I unserialise it with my own logic. But reading from disk is too slow. All - I use parallel processing of this huge datafile and having it on disk would cuase all sorts of contention.

Comment: Using a memoryStrea, all in memory - works perfectly for me - except now my data has outgrown this arbitary maximum size of a bytearray.

Comment: I hope you're done reading your 300 emails first, otherwise no dessert (SO) for you!

Comment: @ManInMoon - then (and also taking into account your comment on memory-mapped files) you'll have to split the data into multiple byte arrays, and either write your own memory-backed stream implementation, or split it at suitable points that allow multiple independent memory streams.

Comment: @Marc Gravell:  I know this is an old question, but I am also reading large blocks of memory into a MemoryStream.  I am considering changing it to MemoryMappedViewStream (with an underlying MemoryMappedFile)  I was worried about performance based on RAM speed vs disk speed, so I'm wondering whether your answer is based more on the size of the stream rather than the speed of the stream.  (If you would rather me post this as a new question, I can.)

Comment: @MrWuf depends on the size, really; you should be able to access mapped files sequentially in chunks, rather than having to load a large part into a memory-stream; up to you though

Comment: @MarcGravell +1 Thanks for the help!  I'm going to try the stream both ways and get some benchmark data for them.